# Is there a .at() equivalent for a multimap?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, multimap

Is there any way to get an iterator to a multimap, for specific keys? For example:

```
multimap<string,int> tmp;
tmp.insert(pair<string,int>("Yes", 1));
tmp.insert(pair<string,int>("Yes", 3));
tmp.insert(pair<string,int>("No", 5));
tmp.insert(pair<string,int>("Maybe", 1));
tmp.insert(pair<string,int>("Yes", 2));

multimap<string,int>::iterator it = tmp.at("Yes);
```

Then I could use `it` for the work I want to do. Is this possible in C++? Or do we have to just cycle through the multimap, element by element, and check for the key before doing the work?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`std::multimap<>::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range), but its kinda hard to tell from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multimap<Key, T>` only sort elements by its `Key`, so we can only find all the elements whose key value equals `"Yes"`, then check each element one by one.

```
typedef multimap<string,int>::iterator Iterator;
pair<Iterator, Iterator> iter_range = tmp.equal_range("Yes");
Iterator it;
for (it = iter_range.first; it != iter_range.second; ++it) {
    if (it->second == 3) {
        break;
    }
}
if (it != tmp.end()) {
    tmp.erase(it);
}
```

In fact it's better to use `multiset<T>` in this case:

```
multiset< pair<string, int> > temp;
temp.insert(make_pair("Yes", 1));
temp.insert(make_pair("Yes", 3));
multiset< pair<string, int> >::iterator iter = temp.find(make_pair("Yes", 1));
if (iter != temp.end()) {
    temp.erase(iter); // it erase at most one element
}
temp.erase(make_pair("Yes", 3)); // it deletes all the elements that equal to make_pair("Yes", 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) for a single key value pair (any matching the key), or [equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to get all of the pairs that match a given key (this seems to be your best bet.)